# Is it true that the recording angels on our shoulders say "Ameen" to the negative things we say/questions we ask?

Tags: quran, hadith, dua, malaikah

Asalam alaikum!

I just had an argument with someone about this, who told me I shouldn't even ask negative questions.

(I asked something along the lines of, "What if the car breaks down?" And he said that I shouldn't ask that, because the angels will say "Ameen" and it'll become true. I said I don't think it works like that, and he got really upset.)

I searched online and I can't find any Hadith or Quranic verse that supports this. Is there any? If someone could point it out for me, that'd be great. (I'm a convert, so I'm still learning!)

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Hm... "What if the car breaks down?" doesn't sound like a du'a (supplication), do you have a better example or could you elaborate? It seems you mixed a few things we have Angels that write down every step and act we make and if we make du'a they might say amen AFAIK there's no backup that them saying amen means it'll become true, but Allah could make it come true if he sees a benefit for us or those whom we supplicate for...